# Concatenate Two dates and their times in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, stored-procedures

I want to concatenate two dates with their times like below in SQL Server 2008. Something like this:

```
2015-09-09 08:30 - 2015-09-09 09:30
```

I tried this method but didn't work and I used casting as well.

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), S.StartTime, 112)+ '-' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), S.endtime, 108)) AS 'OccupiedTime'
```

it is showing result like this

```
2015-09-09 09:30:00:000
```

Comment: Why don't you use format 120?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CONVERT(CHAR(16), s.StartTime, 120) + '-' +
CONVERT(CHAR(16), s.EndTime,   120) AS OccupiedTime
```

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 parts of date - date only + time. You can have 2 strings and concatenate them:

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),s.StartTime,103),'/','-') + ' ' + 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),s.StartTime,114) + ' - ' +  
  REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),s.EndTime,103),'/','-') + ' ' + 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),s.EndTime,114) AS OccupiedDateTime
```

You can make quick check how it looks using:

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),103),'/','-') + ' ' + 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),GETDATE(),114) + ' - ' +  
  REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),103),'/','-') + ' ' + 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),GETDATE(),114) AS OccupiedDateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Convert function and the conversion style parameter together as follows

```
declare @StartTime datetime = getdate()
declare @EndTime datetime = getdate()
select convert(varchar(16), @StartTime, 120) + ' - ' + convert(varchar(16), @EndTime, 120)
```

If you check the code, I used varchar(16) which removes unwanted milllisecond information after conversion.
For more on [SQL Server Convert datetime function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-format-date-format-datetime-t-sql-convert-function.aspx) on action please refer to given tutorial